# gm/Id design characteristics

Tags: adc, circuit, cadence

What are the limitations of the gm/id based analog design methodology employed for sub-micron process nodes? I was reading a research paper that mentioned the design methodology is restricted only to class A devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gm/id methodology can be used for any design where transistors are in the saturation region

Comment: The Paper describes device operation in other regions as well.

Comment: AFAIK gm defined only in a saturation region. How would you define gm in linear?

Comment: There are designs that operate in the subthreshold region as well.

Comment: Subthreshold not very different from saturation. Actually for modern processes, because of low supply voltages, almost all transistors will work in subthreshold